# codeception output Full Cest test signature on run

Tags: codeception

In our tests we use namespaces and we have have some tests that have different namespace but same class name.

For example

```
App\Tests\Acceptance\Single\EventsCest
App\Tests\Acceptance\Recurring\EventsCest
```

But on codeception run the output just shows EventsCest. If there is an error we can see the whole class signature, but in the test passed listing only the class name is shown.

Is there a setting to make codeception list the whole test signature?

Comment: no, there is no such setting

Answer (score 2):

as a workaround we hijack the wantTo-Method

```
$I->wantTo('... ['.  get_class($this).']');
```

it's not very nice but it does the job.